# Monomode microstrip antenna

Tags: antenna, microstrip

Given a microstrip antenna with length a and width b, with a>b, I'm asked to calculate which conditions must satisfy a, b and the frequency so it's a monomode microstrip antenna.

The thing is, as far is I know, a microstrip antenna has infinite modes, so I don't know what I'm being asked.

Comment: I'll have to think, but infinite modes *for the same frequency*?